# Fatal error: [] operator not supported for string error on PHP Array in for loop

Tags: php

I have this PHP Code:

```
for($i=1; $i<=$_POST["counter"]; $i++)
{
    if($_POST["checkbox$i"])
    {
        //select the billing_pdf row
        $sql="SELECT * from billing_pdf_archive where sequence = '".$_POST["checkbox$i"]."' ";
        $rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
        while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
        {
            //now select all contacts for the company who receive all accounts emails
            $sql2="SELECT * from contacts where company_sequence = '".$result["customer_sequence"]."' and receive_accountsemails = 'yes' ";
            $rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
            if(mysql_num_rows($rs2) > 0)
            {
                while($contacts2=mysql_fetch_array($rs2))
                {
                    //generate the list of emails address in an array
                    $emails_list[] = $contacts2["email"];
                }
                $emails_list = implode(',',$emails_list);
            }
        }

        $ins_sql2="INSERT into email_attachments (email_seq, attachment) values ('".$email_sequence."', '".$result["pdf"]."') ";
        $ins_rs2=mysql_query($ins_sql2,$conn) or die(mysql_error());

        $up_sql="UPDATE emails set emailto = '".$emails_list."' where sequence = '".$email_sequence."' ";
        $up_rs=mysql_query($up_sql,$conn);
    }
}
```

but I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings in

on the line that says:

```
$emails_list[] = $contacts2["email"];
```

I am using the same array code on other pages (without the for loop) and they work fine

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can't see `$emails_list = array();` anywhere. Also, could you `var_dump($contacts2["email"]);` just before the critical line?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you fill the array `$emails_list[]` in the second while with `$contacts2["email"]`.
in the next line, you implode the array to a string.

for the next result (first while loop) `$emails_list` is a string. now you can't convert a string to an array

try this:

```
        $emailsListData = array();
        while($contacts2=mysql_fetch_array($rs2))
        {
            //generate the list of emails address in an array
            $emailsListData[] = $contacts2["email"];
        }
        $emails_list = implode(',',$emailsListData);
```

Comment: Better but now you've created the same error as DanFromGermany's answer (look at where `$emails_list` is used).

Comment: This answer is whack according to AD7six because you don't fix all of the crap

Comment: @DanFromGermany "Fix all the crap" means _only_ initializing the array in an appropriate place i.e. line 3 of the code in the question. If it were necessary to rewrite the whole code to avoid the error I'd understand your POV; it isn't, and therefore I don't ;).

Answer (score 2):

You have already used $emails_list as a string some where in your page like 
$emails_list = 7;

and again using it like

$emails_list[] = array(1,2,4);